# Vertical span bands with jqplot

Tags: jqplot, fill, overlays, xrange

I'd like to add vertical span areas on a jqplot by defining for each one the x axis range. Is there an easy and straightforward way to do this ?

I tried setting an overlay with x value set as the centre of the vertical area I want to cover and the linewidth set as the whole x range for the vertical band. The issue is that the linewidth value is encoded in pixel and not in units of xAxis.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please see canvasOverlay on jqplot [documentation here](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-canvasOverlay-js.html) and some [examples here](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/canvas-overlay.html)

You must be able - thanks to them - to display what you need

Comment: I was already aware of those examples my only concern in those is that you cannot set a xmin or xmax option for vertical line so do you have to set the line to the center of the span you want to produce and then set the linewidth to (xmin-xmax) (provided linewidth is explained in terms of xaxis units and not pixels) ?

Comment: I managed to add vertical span bars using linewidth options along with the x value centered on the desired vertical band (since xmax and xmin are not available options for verticalLine overlay objects). As I suspected though the linewidth unit is pixel and not the unit of the xaxis. Is there a way to set the xmin and xmax as xaxis values in a verticalLine overlay ? (if one cannot just do this by tweaking only 2 options in the overlay object it seems to me there is clearly something missing in the overlay plugin anyway).